# JMeter 5.1.1 - Performance Metrics appears different during execution in Non-GUI console and later in GUI Listener for the same Test

Tags: jmeter

Look at the results in Non-GUI Console
[image]

Look at the results in GUI Listener
[image]

It's very strange, I see different results for the same test.

The Average Response Time on Non-GUI Console displays as: **368** ms, whereas it displays **578** ms on Listener

Likewise, the Maximum Response Time on Non-GUI Console displays as: **4524** ms, whereas it displays **9999** ms on Listener

It appears to be happening on Jmeter **5.1.1** version, can someone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the [Summariser](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-two-techniques-get-jmeter-test-results-non-gui-mode/):

   ```
   summary = 9377
   ```
2. In the [Summary Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report):

   ```
   TOTAL = 11941
   ```

My expectation is that the inconsistency is being caused by extra ~2500 sample results in the .jtl results file, to wit you're appending the results of the current test run to the results of the previous test run. JMeter's summariser considers only current session and when you load the .jtl file in the Listener - it calculates the average from all entries in the file.

Consider passing [`-f` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) to your JMeter startup command line like:

```
jmeter -f -n -t test.jms -l result.jtl
```

this way you should get "clean" results and Summariser output will be in line with the Listener output

Comment: Hi Dimitri, 

I did run the test passing the -f option, but no changes in the Sample size. The Sample size is still being conflicted in Non-GUI Summariser and Listener.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Dmitri for pointing out the deviation of Sample size in Summariser and Listener which was causing the other Performance Metrics.

It all worked when I edited the below configuration in the **Jmeter.properties** file

[image]

Thanks